# Resize dock pane tab strip text and buttons in Document docked DockContent

Tags: c#, winforms, dockpanel-suite

I am refactoring a Windows Forms application to scale properly with high DPI settings. This application uses WeiFen Luo's DockPanelSuite library to dock some of its tools (`DockArea.DockLeft`) and the main view area (`DockArea.Document`).

My problem is that main view area tab strip width is often smaller than enclosed caption text width, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81sfY.png). Also, when form is scaled (because moved between screens with differed DPI settings) tab strip buttons are not scaled properly (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mi1d.png)).

I've tried modifying Font size using these properties:

`dockPanel1.Theme.Skin.DockPaneStripSkin.TextFont`
`dockPanel1.Theme.Skin.AutoHideStripSkin.TextFont`

But they do not scale the strip container, only the text inside it.
What can I do to scale tab strip width and buttons in the correct way?

Comment: Patches are welcome as GitHub pull requests, but currently this library does not have much High DPI support.

Comment: I see. I have downloaded dockpanel-suite sources from GitHub and I have read some code (mainly in Themes part), but I can't figure out how to modify code in a proper way. Do you have hint on how to do?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no enough documentation, except http://docs.dockpanelsuite.com/themes/basics.html In most cases, you have to refer to previous commit I made so as to understand what are the building blocks. I also had a few blog posts, https://blog.lextudio.com/tagged/dockpanel-suite

Comment: Thank you, I will check blog posts and I will try to modify dockpanel suite code to di the scaling I need. Maybe I will also add some commit to GitHub (I'm not sure at the moment, it depends on quality of my future changes :-D )

Answer (score 0):

First you should look at code that is used for scaling. Obviously it scales `tab headers` vertical and horizontal but not it's text.

There are two possible solutions to this:

- Rewrite code used for scaling so it also get's `tab font`/ `tab page font` and rescale it
- Create custom extension method

If you go for second method just simple create extension method look at [TextRenderer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer?view=netframework-4.7.2) to measure free space and font size it should go there and then use `tab.Font` to change font on all `tabPages` at once or `tabPage.Font` to change it for each.

Then when you initialize everything just call this method `yourTabControl.ResizeFonts();`

Comment: Sorry, maybe I have not understood what you explained. It seems to me that you are talking about scaling the tab strips of a .NET `TabControl` control. My question is about how to scale the tab strips of a `WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking.DockPane` control (WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking is a third-party DLL).